# Как передать массив с объектами из Activity в Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin

У меня есть `ArrayList<Item>` заполненный объектами. Находится он в `MainActivity`. Как мне передать `ArrayList<Item>` в `ListFragment` для дальнейшего использования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно с ListFragment - можно в активити завернуть данные в адаптер и отдать его во фрагмент `fragment.setListAdapter(adapter);`

Можете сделать свой сеттер во фрагменте, куда отдаете данные и внутри сеттера оборачиваете их в адаптер

А вообще я бы рекомендовал отказаться от ListFragment и взяться за RecyclerView или другой список с переиспользованием View.

Comment: Почему отказаться?

Comment: Закиньте в него 100 элементов и снимите иерархию лайаутов. Все 100 элементов окажутся видимы, по большей части ниже экрана. Каждый из них отрендерен в картинку, которая хранится в оперативной памяти. Расточительство. Повторите эксперимент RecyclerView - увидите в иерархии ровно столько элементов, сколько влезает на экран. Если интересны другие подробности погуглите статьи по RecyclerView, нередко они начинаются с преимуществ над старыми списками, к которым можно отнести ListFragment