# Как в фрагменте ListFragment передать значения переменных из активности

Tags: java, android

Я хочу реализовать TabLayaut в своём приложении ,но у меня всё построено на активности .
Я создал класс Fragment_act
Вот так:

```
public class Fragment_act extends ListFragment {

final String[] catNames = new String[]{ "Category1_name",};
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catNames);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Это мой класс активности из которого я хочу передать данные из переменной.

```
public class ActivityCategoryList1 extends Activity {

GridView listCategory1;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtAlert;

// объявить объект адаптера для создания пользовательского списка категорий
AdapterCategoryList1 cla1;

// создавать переменные arraylist для хранения данных с сервера
static ArrayList<Long> Category1_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category1_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category1_image = new ArrayList<String>();

String Category1API;
int IOConnect = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category1_list);

    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    listCategory1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory1);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

    cla1 = new AdapterCategoryList1(ActivityCategoryList1.this);

    // category API url
    Category1API = Constant.Category1API+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&category1_id=";
    Category1API = Config3.ADMIN3_PANEL_URL + "/api/get-all-category1-data.php" +"?accesskey="+Config3.AccessKey;

    // вызов класса асинтетики для запроса данных с сервера
    new getDataTask().execute();

    // прослушиватель событий для обработки списка при нажатии
    listCategory1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // перейти к странице меню
            Intent iActivityCategoryList = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList1.this, ActivityCategoryList.class);
            iActivityCategoryList.putExtra("category_id", Category1_ID.get(position));

            startActivity(iActivityCategoryList);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Надуть меню; это добавляет элементы в панель действий, если она присутствует.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    // Нажмите здесь пункт «Действие». Панель действий будет
    // автоматически обрабатывать клики на кнопке Home / Up, так долго
    // как вы указываете родительскую активность в AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            IOConnect = 0;
            listCategory1.invalidateViews();
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
            return true;
        case R.id.ic_info:
            // refresh action
            Intent iContact = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList1.this, ActivityContactUs.class);
            startActivity(iContact);
            overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;
        case R.id.cart:
            // refresh action
            Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList1.this, ActivityCart.class);
            startActivity(iMyOrder);
            overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


// clear arraylist variables before used
void clearData(){
    Category1_ID.clear();
    Category1_name.clear();
    Category1_image.clear();
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // анализировать данные json с сервера в фоновом режиме
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // при завершении синтаксического анализа скройте панель прогресса
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

        // если подключение к Интернету и доступное данные показывают данные в списке
        // в противном случае отображать текст предупреждения
        if((Category1_ID.size() > 0) && (IOConnect == 0)){
            listCategory1.setVisibility(0);
            listCategory1.setAdapter(cla1);
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }
}

// метод для анализа данных json с сервера
public void parseJSONData(){

    clearData();

    try {
        // запрашивать данные из API категории
        URL url = new URL(Category1API);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
        connection.connect();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }
        // анализировать данные json и хранить в переменных arraylist
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject category = object.getJSONObject("Category1");

            Category1_ID.add(Long.parseLong(category.getString("Category1_ID")));
            Category1_name.add(category.getString("Category1_name"));
            Category1_image.add(category.getString("Category1_image"));


        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //cla.imageLoader.clearCache();
    listCategory1.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}

}
```

Это сам адаптер

```
class AdapterCategoryList1 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

public AdapterCategoryList1(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ActivityCategoryList1.Category1_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category1_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    holder.imgThumb = (pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);


    //imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+ActivityCategoryList1.Category1_image.get(position), holder.imgThumb);
    Picasso.with(activity).load(Config3.ADMIN3_PANEL_URL + "/" + ActivityCategoryList1.Category1_image.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.imgThumb);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
    ImageView imgThumb;
}



}
```

Подскажите хотя бы один пример передачи данных из активности в фрагмент на основе моего кода.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать массив с объектами из Activity в Fragment?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001105/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-activity-%d0%b2-fragment)

Comment: Просьба "гуглить" до создания вопроса, и сами ответ быстрее получите, и не будете забивать SO кучей одинаковых вопрос. Этот, просто, правда очень часто встречается

Comment: Спасибо. Я отредактировал свой вопрос.

Comment: Курите: http://blog.harrix.org/article/7521

Answer (score 0):

Добавления избыточного количества кода не делает вопрос отличающимся [от кучи других вопросом об этом же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=activity%20fragment%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5). Ну, раз уж так не хочется вникать в старые темы, отвечу тут

```
public class Fragment_act extends ListFragment {

    public void setData(String[] catNames){
         ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>  (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catNames);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Никакой магии не нужно придумывать. Разве что вы можете попробовать положить данные во фрагмент до того, как он был прикреплен, но вроде listFragment адекватно на это реагирует и не будет ругаться или терять данных. Пока вы не положите никаких данных в ListFragment - там будет крутится прогресс бар.

Из вашего вопроса все еще, мягко говоря, не очевидно что вы хотите сделать. Где в активти прикрепляется фрагмент и какие именно данные в него должны быть переданы. Пожалуйста, составляйте вопросы так, чтоб хотя бы очевидные вопросы не приходилось переспрашивать, иначе вас будут заваливать тревогами за качество.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ваш ответ Дмитрий, я ни как не могу разобраться с фрагментами , и поэтому пробую разные варианты в своём фрагменте Fragment_act, в фрагменте я хотел отображать данные из активности ActivityCategoryList1, а затем прикрепить фрагмент к TabListener , чтобы иметь более удобный интерфейс , чем которым я сейчас пользуюсь . Мне хотя бы один пример на основе моего кода. Буду Очень благодарен.